# Magento giving error 503 upon sending emails for New Orders, Invoice, Shipment etc.?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, order-email

I have an ecommerce website built on Magento (1.9.2.3). Last night I shifted it from localhost to online hosting (BigRock) - let's call this live server. The issue is that on live server Magento is not sending any mails. Instead it gives the following error:

> Service Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to
>   maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
>
> Additionally, a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error was
>   encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the
>   request.

The store is not in maintenance mode.

I am using SMTP Pro extension and it's self-test are running fine. On localhost, the same setup is working i.e. I can receive new order, invoice, shipment etc. mails.

I have checked the access logs on online hosting, nothing stands out. Have compared them to the logs on localhost, they both show same request and response sequence.

I have enabled logging in Magento. Got the following in exceptions.log:

https://pastebin.com/rch2BsrX

Following are the content of system.log:

https://pastebin.com/4F6wK35e

If I disable email communication in Magento (in Configuration > System > Mail Sending Settings) everything works fine, except obviously mail functionality is disabled.

I have checked file permissions as well, they are same as on localhost.

Cron settings are as per the guidelines. Though when I access cron.php from the browser it gives error 403.

There's an error_log file in the webroot directory. It says:

> [10-Feb-2018 05:03:03 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SCRIPT_NAME
>   in /cron.php on line 40 [10-Feb-2018 05:03:03 UTC] PHP
>   Notice:  Undefined index: SCRIPT_FILENAME in /cron.php on
>   line 41

Right now, I am not sure where or what the issue is. I have recently begun with Magento development. Can really use some help.

---

Adding my comments here (since I don't have comment privileges as of now):

@Piyush: It's set to 30 seconds on both localhost and Web host

Comment: seems to be issue with your server configurations, check if there is any issue related to `max_execution_time` or other limits

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. Turns out live server was set to the wrong version of PHP. It was set to PHP 5.4. I changed it to PHP 5.6 and things were back to normal.